# Objective-C sorting a NSMutableArray and returning the NSMutableArray (sorted)

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, sorting

Maybe someone can enlighten me on this subject. I'm sorting a `NSMutableArray` declared as `ids`. When I'm done sorting I return it using `return ids;` but for some reason the returned array is not sorted. See this code:

```
NSMutableArray *ids = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

for (Career *career in careers) {
    [ids addObject:[career id]];
}

// Sort the array in an orderly fashion
[ids sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

return ids;
```

This does not return a sorted array.

But if I return the array with the sorting method applied, it will be returned correctly sorted. Like this:

```
//Code is the same as above
return [ids sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Also while I'm at it, I mistakingly used two semi colons (;) when writing the return statement, but I didn't receive any error for doing so?

Comment: `;;` instead of `;` is not a C (or Objective-C) syntax error.

Comment: To add to what Bavarious is saying above, an additional semicolon without an instruction is known as an empty statement. This is allowed so that certain loop/branching constructs can have an empty code block because all the work is in the loop/branching construct itself. Eg. "for (i=1 ; i<=5 ; i++, j+=i);" is a valid for-loop. All this loop really wants to do is add the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 to j so no need for a code-block after the for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-sortedArrayUsingSelector:` returns a new, sorted array, and it doesn’t change the original array. This means that:

```
[ids sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
return ids;
```

does the following:

1. Creates a new, sorted array based on `ids` and keeps `ids` intact;
2. Discards the method return value (i.e., the new, sorted array) since you’re not using it;
3. Returns the original `ids` array.

Whereas:

```
return [ids sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

does the following:

1. Creates a new, sorted array based on `ids` and keeps `ids` intact;
2. Uses the method return value (i.e., the new, sorted array) as the return value.

If you don’t want a new array, use `-sortUsingSelector:` instead:

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't that obvious but now when I checked the documentation it made perfectly sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the array sorted is not the array which receive the message but the return one.
Take a look at [sortedArrayUsingSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)